How to persist job data on every run, not just when there's a change?
I've got a largge Quartz database that uses binary serialization across the board.  I want to migrate everything in the JB to JSON serialization, and I'm using the example here as a guide.
I spin up quarts and configure the persistent job store to use the custom serializer.  It loads all my blob_triggers and re-serializes them back into the database using JSON just fine, but even through it triggers the jobs, it doesn't re-persist the jobdata column in JSON format.
In order to get Quartz to re-write the JobData to the database in the QUARTZ_JOB_DETAILS table, I have to change something in context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.  Here's what I'm doing:
    [PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    [Serializable]
    public class MigrationJob : IJob
    {
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var jobData = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
            var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            jobData["MigratedAt"] = now; // without this line, the data doesn't re-persist
            Console.WriteLine("{0} migrated at at {1}", context.JobDetail.Key.Name, now);
        }
    }

Is there a way to tell quartz to always persist job data rather than only when something about the JobDetails changes?

It should be enough to add and remove some key, it will mark the job data map dirty but doesn't cause it to have more data than before.
[Test]
public void AddAndRemoveSetsDirty()
{
    var map = new JobDataMap();
    map["foo"] = 1;
    map.Remove("foo");
    map.Count.Should().Be(0);
    map.Dirty.Should().BeTrue();
}

